# Getting data from Calendar iOS App from Xcode

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, calendar

I'm developing a Swift based app that requires a way of managing dates and appointments. At first glance I decided to code the calender myself but I thought that it would be far better to get the data straight from the Calendar app to my in dev applicaction and let Calendar manage alerts and appointment creation. With that said, is there a way to do this? Maybe an internal API I can use in order to comunicate with Calendar and get all the appointments in my app, like a JSON or XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an entire framework called [Event Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009662) that's devoted to calendars and reminders. If you use it in your app, you'll have direct access to the user's calendar items. Rather than just using it for importing existing data, you should consider using Event Kit to store your calendar items, so that items that the user enters into your app are also available to and visible in other apps that use Event Kit, such as Calendar and Reminders. To learn how to do all that, you'll want to start with the [*Calendars and Reminders Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).